# Quartus 13.1 installer giving segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, 64-bit, intel-fpga

I'm trying to install Quartus 13.1 on my Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit edition. The downloaded file is a .run installer, which I make executable by executing:

```
sudo chmod +x installer.run
./installer
```

Which gives a segmentation fault (core dumped) message.

I'm posting here because the Altera forums are useless, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to install these packages ?

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5 libmotif4 libxp6 libcurl3
```

And lauching it with bash command directly :

```
$ bash installer
```